# Is it possible to override the button style of a generated javascript code snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A js generated code snippet from a third party places a fixed button on the top of the page and when the button is clicked it shows a modal of a form. I'd like to create a custom button to replace the look of the provided from the snippet but still call the form on the click event. Is that possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pluginInfoandIds"></script>
```

Comment: Can you use CSS to change the style of the button?

Comment: Of course you can. You just need to be able to write a CSS query that locates that generated button. From there, knock yourself out.

Comment: If you can't figure the method out yourself, it is helpful to supply the generated html, so we can give an example

Comment: omg this was so easy, I don't know why sometimes I feel so blocked, all I had to do was override the css of the element

Answer (score 2):

If the button has an id (I assume it has) you should be able to just override the stylesheet information with your own. Through js you should also be able to add/remove classes (provided your script runs after theirs).